# how to define a view modifier that can be applied to a container but only affect the child views of certain type in the container

Tags: swiftui

I define a custom view modifier that only affects a view of certain type. But I have 4 views of that certain type in a container. Now, I can only apply the view modifier to the view for 4 times. How can I apply the view modifier to the container for only 1 time and let the views in the container auto get the view modifier.

EDIT：
My code is something like:

```
VStack{
    otherTypeSubView
    HStack{
        subview1
           .customViewModifierFunc
        subview2
           .customViewModifierFunc
        otherTypeSubView
    }
    subview3
       .customViewModifierFunc
    subview4
       .customViewModifierFunc
}
```

And I want to get the same effect by using:

```
VStack{
        otherTypeSubView
        HStack{
            subview1
            subview2
            otherTypeSubView
        }
        subview3
        subview4
}
 .customViewModifierFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Group`

example:

```
Group {
    Text("Hello,")
    Text("World")
}.font(.title)
```

Comment: "font" can be applied to a container. And all "Text" views in the container can be affected by  "font". This effect is what I want, but how can I define my custom view modifier to get the same ability.

Comment: replace .font with your modifier i.e customViewModifierFunc. if you're asking how you can create the modifier, you can either extend View or create a modifier like this: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/custom-modifiers

Comment: To be more precise，when "Text" view and "Circle" view are in a same vstack, "font" applied to the vstack only produces effect on "Text" NOT "Circle". It's not about how to custom a view modifier, BUT about how to custom a modifier that only affects certain type subview in stead of all subviews in a container.

Comment: what are the different types of your subviews? A way could be to only extend the view type protocol you want to address, e.g. Text or Shape: `struct MyModifier<S>: ViewModifier where S : ShapeStyle`

Comment: @ChrisR In my case, I have 4 custom buttons of the same custom struct type and 2 standard built-in buttons. The outer container is a vstack, and the inner container is a hstack. My custom view modifier is designed to address some matchedGeometryEffect and appearance adjustment work. I want to apply the modifier to the outer vstack and expect the modifier can be auto "drill" into the stack to apply to every custom buttons. For the time being, I can only apply the modifier to the 4 custom buttons separately that seems a little repeated.